# A difficult problem on factorization algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Factorize $(a+b+c)^7 - a^7-b^7-c^7$.

Comment: What if $a=-b?$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that $$(x^7-y^7)=(x-y)\left(\sum_{k=0}^6 x^ky^{6-k}\right)$$
which implies that $(a+b)$, $(b+c)$ and $(c+a)$ are factors.

Answer (score 0):

When $a=-b$,

$$(a+b+c)^7-a^7-b^7-c^7=c^7-a^7-(-a)^7-c^7=0$$

By Factor Theorem, $a+b$ is a factor of $(a+b+c)^7-a^7-b^7-c^7$.

Similarly, $b+c$ and $c+a$ are also factors of $(a+b+c)^7-a^7-b^7-c^7$.

As $(a+b+c)^7-a^7-b^7-c^7$ is cyclic and symmetric,

$$(a+b+c)^7-a^7-b^7-c^7=(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)[p(a^4+b^4+c^4)+q(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)+r(a^3b+a^3c+b^3a+b^3c+c^3a+c^3b)+sabc(a+b+c)]$$

for some constants $p$, $q$, $r$ and $s$.

Comparing the coefficients of $a^6b$, we have

$$7=p$$

Comparing the coefficients of $a^5b^2$, we have

$$\binom{7}{2}=p+r$$

Comparing the coefficients of $a^4b^3$, we have

$$\binom{7}{3}=q+r$$

Comparing the coefficients of $a^4b^2c$, we have

$$\binom{7}{4}\binom{3}{2}=p+q+3r+s$$

Therefore, $p=7$, $q=21$, $r=14$ and $s=35$.

$$(a+b+c)^7-a^7-b^7-c^7=7(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)[a^4+b^4+c^4+3(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)+2(a^3b+a^3c+b^3a+b^3c+c^3a+c^3b)+5abc(a+b+c)]$$

It remains to show that

$$g(a,b,c)=a^4+b^4+c^4+3(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)+2(a^3b+a^3c+b^3a+b^3c+c^3a+c^3b)+5abc(a+b+c)$$

is irreducible.

If $\alpha a+\beta b+\gamma c$ is a factor of $g(a,b,c)$, then so are $\alpha a+\beta c+\gamma a$, $\alpha b+\beta a+\gamma c$, $\alpha b+\beta c+\gamma a$, $\alpha c+\beta a+\gamma b$ and  $\alpha c+\beta b+\gamma a$.

If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are mutually distinct, then the product of these factors has degree $6$.

So at least two of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are equal, say $\beta=\gamma$. But then

$$[\alpha a+\beta (b+c)][\alpha b+\beta (c+a)][\alpha c+\beta (a+b)]$$

is a factor of degree $3$ of $g(a,b,c)$ and thus there is one more cyclic and symmetric linear factor left. This factor should be $a+b+c$.

However, when $a=-b-c$,

$$(a+b+c)^7-a^7-b^7-c^7=(b+c)^7-b^7-c^7\ne0$$

and hence $a+b+c$ cannot be a factor of $g(a,b,c)$.

Therefore, $g(a,b,c)$ has no linear factors.

$g(a,b,c)$ either has no factors or only has cyclic and symmetric quadratic factors, i.e.

$$g(a,b,c)=[a^2+b^2+c^2+m(ab+bc+ca)][a^2+b^2+c^2+n(ab+bc+ca)]$$

Comparing the coefficients of $a^3b$,

$$2=m+n$$

Comparing the coefficients of $a^2bc$,

$$5=m+n$$

Such pair of $m$ and $n$ does not exist.

$g(a,b,c)$ is irreducible.